# Flutter (Screen recorder) Securing Music stream App, IOS & Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is there a flutter solution to securing music app from screen recorder (Even the app runs  in the background), like apple music app did, stop the music when you start screen recorder. We have tried [windowmanager package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager) & [secure application](https://pub.dev/packages/secure_application/example)  but no one works in IOS.
We have a mobile app to stream music, the app implement in-app purchase, every song should be bought before listening, and the content is exclusive for the app. that's why we need to secure the app, we have searched a lot for flutter packages and native implementations but we haven’t find a solution for IOS specific .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement this natively for iOS.

Use `isCaptured` property in `UIScreen` to know if screen recording is happening (you can do this for iOS 11+)

You can use Key-Value Observing to know when `isCaptured` changes

Apple says:

> To prevent the system from recording the audio portion, observe the isCaptured property and take appropriate action in your app as described...

[see the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921651-iscaptured)

**EDIT:**

I've found this library [flutter_forbidshot](https://github.com/qq326646683/flutter_forbidshot) it is helpful, and I think it is suitable for this problem.

Comment: Good answer, ok consider I did that in AppDelegate.swift file, and now I can print if it's captured or not. Did you have any idea how can I listen to that from my app flutter and stop the music for example or do anything ?

Comment: @A.Bechir you don't have to exactly listen  for screen recording, **the easy way** is to call a native method from flutter (like every 10 second when you are playing the music) and stop music if you detect screen recording. to do this check out this [link](https://pahlevikun.medium.com/bridging-between-dart-and-native-code-with-flutter-channel-for-communicate-each-other-7c736929ee42)  **BUT** if you want the native code to trigger this you need to use Callbacks [link](https://testfairy.com/blog/native-communication-with-a-callback-in-flutter/)

Comment: @A.Bechir Also [flutter_forbidshot](https://github.com/qq326646683/flutter_forbidshot) is good, you can use it as is or use parts of the code in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's a fresh flutter solution.
Now there's a new plugin named [flutter_prevent_screen_recording](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_prevent_screen_recording).
You can check whether the screen is being recorded or not with this plugin. In addition,it's for ios.